# Vue 3 options api, how to scroll to an anchor via ID

Tags: vue.js

I have Vue 3 + vue-router for navigation through pages in an app.
I would like to navigate to #download at HomeView from a different pages and from
HomeView it self. **But it doesn't working**

My Navbar

```
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link :to="{ path: '/#download' }">
              <a class="nav-link me-lg-3">Download</a>
            </router-link>
          </li>
```

My HomeView

```
  <section class="bg-gradient-primary-to-secondary" id="download"></section>
```

The route set-up:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "about",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "@/views/AboutView.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/privacy-policy",
    name: "PrivacyPolicyView",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "@/views/PrivacyPolicyView.vue"),
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash,
      } as any;
    }
  },
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code has worked for me:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    } else {
      return {
        el: to.hash,
        behavior: "smooth",
      };
    }
  },
});
```

[Vue router Info](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)